# Difference in meaning between "He wanted her to buy the book" and "He hoped her buy the book"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between "He wanted her to buy the book" and
"He hoped her buy the book"?

Can "He wanted her to buy the book" be used in the situation, "She did not intend to buy the book. He asked her to buy the book"?

Can "He hoped her buy the book" be used in the situation, "She tried to buy the book. He cheered for her to buy the book"?

Can "He hoped her to buy the book" be used in the situation, "She did not intend to buy the book. He cheered for her to buy the book"?

Comment: *He hoped her buy the book* is ***not valid English***. One valid way of expressing what you probably mean to say is *He hoped **[that] she would** buy the book.* But I don't really understand what you're asking about here. Given that you say she ***tried*** to buy the book, might you be getting confused between ***to hope*** (to *desire / wish for* something) and ***to help*** (to *assist / aid* someone or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentences with "hope" are not grammatically correct.  Unlike "want", hope doesn't take an indirect object.  However we can *hope* for someone to do something.

> I hope **she will buy** the book.

We also commonly use the present tense with "hope", even for future actions

> I hope she **buys** the book.

If talking about a past hope, what we hope to happen may or may not be in the past, so we have to conjugate it separately.

> I hoped she **would buy** the book (and she did).  (past hope, past action)
>
> I hoped she **will buy** the book (but now I don't think she will). (past hope, future action)

The difference between "want" and "hope" is subtle and internal and difficult to define.  I would recommend using a translation dictionary in the *hope* that your native language has separate words for these.

However, to give it a try: To *want* is a general way to express a desire for something, e.g. *"I want a cookie"*.

Meanwhile, to *hope* is akin to *wish*, that is, to want something without expectation that it will happen, or without any power to make it happen, or by appealing to someone else (including a deity) to make it happen, e.g. *"I hope my friend brings me some cookies"*.

Comment: I heard that we need to write "to" in the sentence with "want", and we can not use "to" in the sentence with "hope". What is the significance of "to" to make such a big difference? In that sentence, does the "to" express the intensity of the speaker's emotion?

Comment: want, hope, and wish, I really use it in the same sense. By the way, why can "to" be used for "want" and why can not "to" be used for "hope"? Does "to" have any special meaning?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using "to" with "hope":  *I hope to go to the Moon someday*.  But as I said, want and hope are not the same thing.

Comment: If so, can we use "I hope her to go to the Moon someday" like “I want her to go to the the Moon someday”?

Comment: @user22046  No.  As I explain in my answer, *hope* doesn't take an indirect object.  *I hope she goes to the Moon someday* would be the correct grammar.

Comment: Thank you for your faithful reply. But I do not know why We can not use an indirect object for "hope". If "indirect objects" can be used in "want", I have no idea why "hope",which does not make a difference in meaning, can not be used "indirect objects".
Surely there will be a difference. what difference is there? My question is that I do not know what is so natural? Indeed, I have no idea why some verbs with a similar meaning can use their indirect objects and others can not use their indirect objects.

Comment: Andrew // You say that to hope is akin to wish, that is, to want something without expectation that it will happen, If so, does the  "to" mean "speaker's expectation" ?  Is "to" written to express the speaker's expectations? Does the "hope" without the speaker's expectation make it impossible to use the indirect object and  the "to" after the indirect object?

Comment: @user22046  I don't know *why* English grammar is a certain way.  It just is.  Sometimes there's an explanation, but sometimes the explanation is "this is just how people talk".  I'm sure in your own native language there are idiomatic grammar structures that don't make sense.   Also, I'm not sure I'm explaining it correctly when I say "hope doesn't take an indirect object".   It's difficult to give a deep English lesson in few words.

Comment: @user22046  Plus, as I said before, it's difficult to explain the difference between "want" and "hope" even to English speakers.  We *know* the difference, of course, but it's hard to explain without using examples.  Here is a technical page with some of these examples:  https://wikidiff.com/want/hope